# Problem with WIFI dongle going to sleep

Tags: usb, wifi

I have a raspberry pi 2 with a canakit WIFI USB (RT5370).

If there's no traffic to the raspberry for about 10 seconds (eg, not typing in my SSH connection), it will go into sleep mode or some sort. 
I have tried turn off power management as suggested by my sources online but no luck:

```
$ iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"koikoi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: C0:C1:C0:2D:8F:B2   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:118  Invalid misc:4   Missed beacon:0
```

Unable to ping the Raspberry Pi 2 after the interface goes to 'sleep'

```
$ ping 192.168.1.146
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: Host is down
ping: sendto: Host is down
ping: sendto: Host is down
ping: sendto: Host is down
```

At this point, the only way to get the connection alive is to ping out from the Raspberry Pi to the router (192.168.1.1)

Alive again:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.146
PING 192.168.1.146 (192.168.1.146): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.146: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=4.242 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.146: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.992 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.146: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.717 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.146: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=4.222 ms
```

I've added a cron to ping my router every other second but this isn't ideal. I'm looking for a real solution - any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you upgraded all packages with 'sudo apt-get update' followed by 'sudo apt-get upgrade'.  It seems to me when I had a canakit dongle that's what solved the behavior you describe.

Comment: Found the article I used http://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-set-up-the-ralink-rt5370-wifi-dongle-on-raspian

Comment: Thanks Tyson, all packages are up to date. The WIFI is setup fine, just like that tutorial. Still having issues : (

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem with one of my dongles I added

```
@reboot              (sleep 30; /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off)&
```

To the root crontab.

That appeared to solve the problem for me.  Of course this might have been coincidental and perhaps it coincided with a kernel update.

Perhaps call every 5 minutes or so rather than just at boot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the power saving mode is already off. Something weird is happening here.